# Getting error while trying to parse dates in python

Tags: pandas, datetime, format, strftime

I have a dataset like this

> df_NO2
>
> ```
>   rec                             pm1 pm2p5   pm10
> 0 2019-05-31T13:42:27.514+00:00   1.8 43.8    3.5
> 1 2019-05-31T13:42:37.497+00:00   1.6 46.4    3.3
> 2 2019-05-31T13:42:47.497+00:00   1.8 88.4    4.5
> 3 2019-05-31T13:42:57.498+00:00   2.8 34.9    5.4
> 4 2019-05-31T13:43:07.499+00:00   2.9 93.8    6.9
> ```

I wanted to change the date and time format of "rec" column to

> df_NO2

```
         rec                    pm1 pm2p5   pm10
0   2019-05-31 13:42:27         1.8  43.8   3.5
1   2019-05-31 13:42:37         1.6  46.4   3.3
2   2019-05-31 13:42:47         1.8  88.4   4.5
3   2019-05-31 13:42:57         2.8  34.9   5.4
4   2019-05-31 13:43:07         2.9  93.8   6.9
```

I have tried using the code

```
import dateutil.parser

d = dateutil.parser.parse(df_NO2['rec'])
print(d.strftime('%yyyy-%mm-%dd %hh:%mm'))
```

But I am getting an error message

```
Parser must be a string or character stream, not Series.
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pd.to_datetime(df_NO2.rec).dt.strftime(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M)
```

Output:

```
0    2019-05-31 13:42
1    2019-05-31 13:42
2    2019-05-31 13:42
3    2019-05-31 13:42
4    2019-05-31 13:43
```

`df_NO2['rec']` returns a whole column (series) which can't be processed by strftime. Instead, you need to apply strftime to each element of the series.

Besides, you got the format specifiers wrong, see e.g. [here](http://strftime.org/) for reference.